# How can I incorporate if statement when calculating IRR in R?

Tags: r, if-statement, irr

This is a simple function I use to calculate IRR. However, there are incidences when all cash flows are negative and return "Error in uniroot(npv, c(0, 1), cf = cf) :   f() values at end points not of opposite sign." Is there any way I can put if statement so that when IRR can't be computed, R simply returns 0?

```
npv<-function(i,cf,t=seq(along=cf)) sum (cf/(1+i)^t)
irr <- function(cf) {uniroot(npv, c(0,1), cf=cf)$root }
irr(cf)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the `all` function:

```
irr <- function(cf) {
              if(all(cf < 0)) return(0)
              uniroot(npv, c(0,1), cf=cf)$root
       }
```

- If the `all` function returns TRUE, the `return` function will return 0 and then exit the function.
- If the `all` function returns FALSE, then the `uniroot` function will run as it did previously.

Answer (score 1):

I should mention that even after the accepted answer your functions seem to contain a small error:

```
npv<-function(i,cf,t=seq(along=cf)) sum (cf/(1+i)^t)
irr <- function(cf) {
    if(all(cf < 0)) return(0)
    uniroot(npv, c(0,1), cf=cf)$root
}
```

Which considering this example:

```
> npv(c(-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100), i = 0.025)
[1] 8528.911
```

The problem is that the defaults for `t=seq(along=cf)` will make you discount the cash flows by `1:4`. Since the initial cash outflow of `-123400` is usually considered a PV, you end up out of sync for the discounting.

This should fix things:

```
npv<-function(i,cf,t=seq(along=cf)-1) sum (cf/(1+i)^t)
```

Giving you this:

```
> npv(c(-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100), i = 0.025)
[1] 8742.134
```

But generally I would use `financial` or `FinCal` for computing IRR or NPV (or MIRR):

```
> require(financial)
> cf(c(-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100), i = 2.5)

Cash Flow Model

Flows:
      1       2       3       4 
-123400   36200   54800   48100 

 IRR%: 5.96 
 NPV Extremes at I%:  

   I%     NPV     NFV     NUS
1 2.5 8742.13 9414.32 3060.95

> require(FinCal)
> npv(c(-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100), r = 0.025)
[1] 8742.134
> irr(c(-123400, 36200, 54800, 48100))
[1] 0.05959787
```

Answer (score 0):

IRR may fail in may more instances than just when all cash flows are zero. To cater for every one of those scenarios you may want to `tryCatch`the error, instead.

```
npv<-function(i,cf,t=seq(along=cf)) sum (cf/(1+i)^t)
irr <- function(cf) {tryCatch(uniroot(npv, c(0,1), cf=cf)$root,
         error=function(e) return(NA))
        }

irr(cf)
```