# Investment decision-making: NPV, IRR, PB calculation in R

Tags: r

I am trying to calculate the net present value (NPV), internal rate of return (IRR) and the payback (PB) time for a varying number of projects in order to evaluate, which investment project offers the best return.

[image]

So far I am able to calculate it in several lines of code for each project individually. But what i am trying to do is: writing a function which accepts a matrix containing a number of different projects and their cash flows and automatically returning NPV, IRR and PB. The function should accept the risk-free rate (interest rate) for discounting the cash flows as an additional input parameter.

Does anybody have an idea on how to tackle this? On how to write a function which gives back a matrix with the results?

The code for calculating each measure itself looks like this:

```
library(FinCal)

#NPV Project 1 & Project 2
NPV.Project1 <- NPV(-1000, c(1250, 10, 10, 20, 20), c(1:5), 0.06 ) 
NPV.Project2 <- NPV(-1000, c(-10, 0, 10, 20, 2000), c(1:5), 0.06 )

#Solution: NPV2 with 509 > NPV1 with 227 -> Pick Project 2

#IRR Project 1 & Project 2
IRR.Project1 <- IRR(-1000, c(1250, 10, 10, 20, 20), c(1:5))
IRR.Project2 <- IRR(-1000, c(-10, 0, 10, 20, 2000), c(1:5))
#Solution: IRR.Project1 with 28% > IRR.Project2 with 15% -> Pick Project 1

#PB Project 1 & Project 2
#PB Project 1
cf0 <- -1000
cf <- c(1250, 10, 10, 20, 20)
t <- 5

temp <- 0

#Calculating the Payback period
for (i in 1:5){
  temp[i]=sum(cf[1:i])
}
for (i in 1:5){
  if ((temp[i]+cf0) > 0){
    payback.Project1 <- i
    break
  }
  print(payback.Project1)
}

#PB Project 2
cf0 <- -1000
cf <- c(-10, 0, 10, 20, 2000)
t <- 5

temp <- 0

#Calculating the Payback period
for (i in 1:5){
  temp[i]=sum(cf[1:i])
}
for (i in 1:5){
  if ((temp[i]+cf0) > 0){
    payback.Project2 <- i
    break
  } 
  print(payback.Project2)
}
#Solution: Period for PB with Project 1 is way smaller (1 year) than with  Project 2 (5 years)
```

Comment: Error: could not find function "NPV"

Comment: Yeah, it seems you are using old version of `FinCal` package. Could you post your `SessionInfo` here?

Comment: sorry guys, i posted the wrong package, it s the package "FinancialMath", not "FinCal"!

Answer (score 4):

Your data:

```
cf_df <- data.frame(
  Project1 = c(-1000, 1250, 10, 10, 20, 20),
  Project2 = c(-1000, -10, 0, 10, 20, 2000)
)
```

Here are some useful functions that you might consider keeping around for working with capital budgeting problems:

```
dcf <- function(x, r, t0=FALSE){
  # calculates discounted cash flows (DCF) given cash flow and discount rate
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # r - vector or discount rates, in decimals. Single values will be recycled
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE, i.e. discount rate in first period is zero.
  if(length(r)==1){
    r <- rep(r, length(x))
    if(t0==TRUE){r[1]<-0}
    }
  x/cumprod(1+r)
 }

npv <- function(x, r, t0=FALSE){
  # calculates net present value (NPV) given cash flow and discount rate
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # r - discount rate, in decimals
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE
  sum(dcf(x, r, t0))
 }

pbp <- function(x, ...){
  # calculates payback period (PBP)
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # ... - ignored
  i <- match(1, sign(cumsum(x)))
  i-2+(-cumsum(x)[i-1]/x[i])
 }

dpbp <- function(x, r, t0=FALSE){
  # calculates discounted payback period (DPBP) given cash flow and discount rate
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # r - discount rate, in decimals
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE
  pbp(dcf(x, r, t0))
 }

irr <- function(x, t0=FALSE, ...){
  # calculates internal rate of return (IRR) given cash flow 
  #
  # x - cash flows vector
  # t0 - cash flow starts in year 0, default is FALSE
tryCatch(uniroot(f=function(i){sum(dcf(x, i, t0))}, 
                 interval=c(0,1))$root,
         error=function(e) return(NA)
        )
  }
```

Combine these functions with the power of `dplyr` and you will have a toolbox capable of competing with the CFO's favorite spreadsheet:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(forcats)

cf_df %>%
  summarise_all(funs(NPV=npv,PBP=pbp, DPBP=dpbp, IRR=irr), r=0.06, t0=TRUE) %>% 
  gather(key=key, value = value) %>% 
  separate(key, into = c("Project", "Metric")) %>% 
  spread(key=Project, value=value) %>% 
  mutate(Metric=fct_relevel(Metric, "NPV", "IRR", "PBP", "DPBP"),
         Metric=fct_recode(Metric, 
                           `Net Present Value (NPV), USD mln`="NPV", 
                           `Internal Rate of Return (IRR), %`="IRR",
                           `Payback Period, years` = "PBP",
                           `Discounted Payback Period, years`="DPBP")) %>% 
  arrange(as.numeric(Metric))

#                            Metric    Project1    Project2
#1 Net Present Value (NPV), USD mln 227.3284770 509.3204496
#2 Internal Rate of Return (IRR), %   0.2808485   0.1508404
#3            Payback Period, years   0.8000000   4.4900000
#4 Discounted Payback Period, years   0.8480000   4.6592072
```

Comment: Cheers mate, this one helped a lot, although it is definitely more complex than the first solution!

Comment: @Lukes solution comes in first two lines. Everything else is icing on the cake to produce nicely looking summary table. Please accept one of the solutions and upvote those you found useful

Answer (score 1):

```
 W=function(data,rate){
   NPV=apply(data,1,npv,r=rate)
   IRR=apply(data,1,irr)
   PB=apply(data,1,function(x)min(which(cumsum(x)[-1]>0)))
   data.frame(NPV=NPV,IRR=IRR,PB=PB)
 }

 funfun=function(data,r){
 mapply(apply,list(data),1,c(function(x)npv(r,x),irr,function(x)min(which(cumsum(x)[-1]>0))))
 }

W(dat,0.06)
       NPV       IRR PB
A 227.3285 0.2808516  1
B 509.3204 0.1508564  5

 funfun(dat,0.06)
      [,1]      [,2] [,3]
A 227.3285 0.2808516    1
B 509.3204 0.1508564    5
```

Of course you can give the final matrix column names. Hope this helps

Here is the matrix data used:

```
dat= structure(c(-1000, -1000, 1250, -10, 10, 0, 10, 10, 20, 20, 20, 
 2000), .Dim = c(2L, 6L), .Dimnames = list(c("A", "B"), NULL))
```

Comment: perfect, thank you so much!! didnt expect a solution in code that small!!

Comment: If this answers your question, you can accept the solution to close this question. You can also upvote the solution for others to be able to see that this is what you were looking for.